# Vue: Convert code from Options to Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to convert the following code form `options` to `composition` API in Vue using Typescript.

```
data() {
    return {
      items: [
        'Car',
        'Truck',
        'Bike',
        'Caravan'
      ],
      activeItem: 0,
      show: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showDropdown() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    },
    setActiveItem(item) {
      this.activeItem = this.items.indexOf(item);
      this.show = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dropdownItems() {
      return this.items.filter((item,i) => i !== this.activeItem)
    }
  }
```

This is what I have. I am still new to Vue and Typescript so i am using this example to learn more about composition API and Typescript.

```
setup() {
    const activeItem = 0;
    const show = ref(false);

    const items = ref([
        'Car',
        'Truck',
        'Bike',
        'Caravan'
    ]);

    function showDropdown(this: any) {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }

    function setActiveItem(this: any, item: string) {
      this.activeItem = this.items.indexOf(item);
      this.show = false;
    }

    const dropdownItems = computed(function (this: any, item: string) {
      return this.items.filter((item, i) => i !== this.activeItem);
    });

    return {
      activeItem,
      show,
      items,
      showDropdown,
      setActiveItem,
      dropdownItems,
    };
  },
```

The errors I am getting are for example in the `setActiveItem` method is `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.` So when I pass `this: any` params it works but I don't know if this is the right way to do it?
Second problem is I can't get the computed method to work I don't know how to implement it correctly. Is there someone who can help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The objective of composition API is to get rid of dynamic `this` that isn't an instance of a specific class but an object that aggregates properties from component definition and puts limitations on TypeScript typing.

Instead, variables defined in the scope of `setup` are supposed to be accessed directly:

```
const dropdownItems = computed((item: string)  => {
  return unref(items).filter((item, i) => i !== unref(activeItem));
});
```

`activeItem` is supposed to be a ref as well.

Answer (score 1):

Computed method you just import `import { ref, computed } from "@vue/reactivity";`. With `ref` you need to use `value`. (Following code is without typescript)

```
import { ref, computed } from "@vue/reactivity";

setup() {
const activeItem = ref(0);
const show = ref(false);
const items = ref([
    'Car',
    'Truck',
    'Bike',
    'Caravan'
]);

const dropdownItems = computed(() => items.value.filter((item, i) => i !== activeItem.value));

const showDropdown = () => {
  show.value = !show.value;
}

const setActiveItem = (item) => {
  activeItem.value = items.value.indexOf(item);
  show.value = false;
}

return {
  activeItem,
  show,
  items,
  showDropdown,
  setActiveItem,
  dropdownItems,
};
},
```